# Vector can't be NULL, What should I return instead of NULL?

Tags: c++, vector, return

I want to return an alternate to NULL for the `vector` as vectors can't be NULL also I don't want to return an empty vector its already returned in another condition.

```
std::vector<int> how_sum(long target_sum, std::vector<int> numbers, std::map<int, std::vector<int>> &memo)
{
    . . .

    if (target_sum == 0)
        return {};    // empty vector returned here

    if (target_sum < 0)
        // return an alternate to NULL vector

    . . .
}
```

Comment: How can a `std::vector` be `NULL` ?

Comment: `NULL` is a scalar value, `std::vector` is a class, they are not compatible.

Comment: A `std::vector<int>` is not a pointer, and can never be `NULL`. It also cannot be the integer value `0`. Are you trying to return an empty vector?

Comment: @paolo then what should I return instead of NULL?

Comment: I'm probably missing something here - why ca't you just return the empty vector? I would even simplify the code: at the end, always `return res`. You can replace the existing `reeturn` statement with a `break`.

Comment: @MSalters because I already returned an empty vector when target_sum is 0; Actually I solved the problem by returning a vector containing -1 since in this problem vector can only contain positive numbers solved my problem but I can't think of any other solution, Thanks I'll simplify code by `break`

Comment: The `target_sum<0` looks like a `std::invalid_argument` exception at first glance, but hen you would want to avoid calling `how_sum` recursively when `target_sum-sum` is negative. This is a standard thing with recursive functions: you often want a non-recursive   wrapper to deal with error checking etcetera, parts that are needed only once and not recursively

Comment: Return `std::optional<std::vector<T>>`. Or throw an exception on failure.